# Integration by parts on a manifold

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms

$M$ is a closed Riemannian manifold, I want to break the following integration on $M$ using integration by parts techniques which I am not so familiar with.
\begin{align*}
\int_M\langle d\beta,\omega\rangle|\phi|^2 dV
\end{align*}
Here $\phi$ is a section of a complex line bundle with a compatible metric on it, $\beta$ is a $3$-form and $\omega$ is a Harmonic four form on the manifold.

Comment: First, you're integrating a function, not a top-degree form. I assume the $\star 1 = dV$ is understood? You might start by noting that $\langle d\beta,\omega\rangle {\star} 1 = d\beta\wedge\star\omega$ and remember that $d\omega = d{\star}\omega = 0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin yeah $dV$ should be added. I edited it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: what means here the product $\langle \,\cdot\, ,\,\cdot\,  \rangle $? It is some kind of dot product of forms? Maybe the dot product that its usually defined in the exterior algebra induced from an inner product space?

Comment: @Masacroso sorry I meant the usual inner product using the Hodge-star operator, I added the term "Riemannian" now.

Comment: You can write the integrand as $\langle d\beta, |\phi|^2 \omega \rangle dV$ and using the definition of formal adjoint of d to get $d^*$